# Compiling error that says 'std::basic_string<charT, _Traits, _Alloc>

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, codeblocks

The question was to iterate through a paragraph until an empty line is met.

Here's the code that's giving me the error mentioned in the title

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string word;
   vector<string>text;
   while(cin>>word)
   {
       text.push_back(word);
   }
   for(auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end() && !(*it).empty; it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
```

What is causing the error, and what's the fix?

I'm a beginner, just started iterators.

Comment: Although the problem with this one was not very hard to see, next time please provide the full error message (or at least the first and last ~10 lines).

Comment: How do I end the while(cin>>word) loop? I just keep inputting words. It doesn't go out of the loop. Sorry I'm a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty` is a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string word;
   vector<string>text;
   while(cin>>word)
   {
       text.push_back(word);
   }
   for(auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end() && !(*it).empty(); it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I end the  while(cin>>word) loop?
I just keep inputting words. It doesn't go out of the loop.
Sorry I'm a beginner